# Is it possible to use values from another table as the interval in a DATEADD function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, dateadd

I have a table of **events** containing a date (smalldatetime).
I have a table of **intervals** (int) (days before) for when a reminder should be sent - `DATEADD(D, *interval*, GETDATE())`.

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to get all the events where a reminder should be sent today (based on `GETDATE()` from the DATEADD function. This is instead of me first getting all the intervals and running SQL in a loop, passing each interval as a parameter into the DATEADD function.

Any ideas how I'd do this?

```
**dbo.events**
id (int) PK
date (smalldatetime)
customerID (int)

**dbo.intervals**
id (int) PK
daysBefore (int)
customerID (int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. I can't draw this query for you due to lack of information provided. But yes, you can.

Take this example:

```
MyTable:
ID    Interval    Date
1     1           10-10-2001

SELECT ID, DATEADD(D, Interval, GETDATE()) AS NewDate FROM MyTable


SELECT e.*
FROM [events] e
INNER JOIN [interval] i on e.customerID = i.customerID
WHERE e.date = DATEADD(D, i.daysBefore, 
                   DATEADD(D, 0, 
                       DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Thanks - while I think the JOIN is better than the IN statement I wrote, the execution plan shows the same thing happening (except for a Right Semi Join when using the IN statement vs the Inner Join, although this makes no difference).

Comment: @IgorK. If they have the same execution plan, take the one you (and your team if applicable) will find most readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should have tried it yourself

```
create table t(val int);
insert into t values(4),(7),(10)

select DATEADD(D, val, GETDATE()) from t
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d74a/1)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for showing how that's possible. I presume this would be how to write the SQL, unless there is a more efficient way?

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE date IN (
    SELECT DATEADD(D,daysBefore,DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())))
    FROM interval
    WHERE events.customerID = customerID);
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba053/4)**