# change only the month of a date in sql

Tags: sql

i have a column `readiness_dt` which is a date in `mm/dd/yyyy` .I want to update the month of this date to the value present in another column `month`. Is there a query to just modify the month for a date.
E.g. readiness_dt      month
      02/14/2013       06
I want a function which should change the readiness_dt  to 06/14/2013

Comment: You should modify your question with examples of the data, desired results, and tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DATEADD (month, 'your column name from 
      another table','xx/xx/xxxx') 
from 'your other table'
```

Example:

```
    create table date_test(
    interval int)

    insert into date_test values (1)

    insert into date_test values (2)

    insert into date_test values (3)

    select * from date_test

    select GETDATE() as Cur_date, DATEADD(month,interval,GETDATE()) as Interval_Added     

    from date_test
```

Please check this as well

[Is it possible to use values from another table as the interval in a DATEADD function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001876/is-it-possible-to-use-values-from-another-table-as-the-interval-in-a-dateadd-fun)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 4, '02/14/2013 ')
```

Comment: I don't want it just for this record , I want to replace the readiness_dt for the whole table , I cant just add 4 to every column in the month of readiness_dt.